# pandas merge dataframes where rows match and append value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames:

df1:

```
   Chr  Pos   qual
0  1    1234  2
1  2    5678  6
2  1    1111  4
3  5    0123  30
```

df2:

```
   Chr   Pos
0  1     1234
1  5     0123
2  3     1111
3  1     01234
```

if the row in df2 matches the row in df1 then append qual value to df2.
If not then Keep the rows in df2 but add NaN to df2.

Desired Output:

```
   Chr   Pos   qual
0  1     1234  2
1  1     1111  NaN
2  1     01234 NaN
3  2     5678  NaN
4  3     1111  NaN
5  5     0123  30
```

Note that in this case the Pos column need to remain as strings.

```
data = {'Chr':[1,2,1,5],
    'Pos':['1234','5678','1111','0123'],
    'qual':[2,6,4,30]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'Chr':[1,5,3,1],
     'Pos':['1234','0123','1111','01234']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I have tried using pd.merge() and iterrows but can't seem to get the desired output.

thanks.

Comment: you need [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Check on SO, there are plenty of examples doing this.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on=['Chr','Pos'], how='right')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly should be:

```
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on=['Chr','Pos'],indicator=True)
df3.loc[df3._merge != "both",'qual']= np.nan 
df3.drop(columns='_merge',inplace=True)
df3
```